# WebBrowser Control works in Office 2010 but not working in Office 365 / 2016

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, ms-word

### VBA UserForm Webbrowser control keeps throwing error messages

I added a WebBrowser control to a UserForm like this:

> Right Click on ToolBox > Additional Controls > MicrosoftWebBrowser

In Office 2010 I'm able to point the Browser to various websites and they load without issue, for example:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate "https://stackoverflow.com"
End Sub
```

In Office 2010 everything works as expected, SO Loads, looks great and there are no errors.

**However**, I have 2 laptops running Office 365 - both laptops fail to fully load SO. An Error message is thrown: `An error has occurred in the script on this page... Line: 0, Char: 0, ...`

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

*... excluding using `Me.WebBrowser1.Silent = True` ;-)*

---

On a `testpage.js` I've found that I can add this: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` to the html and everything works. But that won't help with pages that I am unable to control... Are there any options?